# XSL-FO: Looking for If-statement to detect odd or even page.

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to find a way to detect if the page being generated is odd or even in a template to left/right justify content. For example, a block of text with symbol next to it. The symbol would be left justified on one page, and right justified on the next.

I don't think checking fo:page-number is possible. And I can't figure out a way that would work with region-start/region-end because the symbol wouldn't line up with it's associated block of text in region-body.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="EvenPage">
    <fo:region-body />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="OddPage">
    <fo:region-body />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="OddPage" odd-or-even="odd"/>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="EvenPage" odd-or-even="even"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="Content">      
  <fo:flow>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no if-statement to detect an odd or even page.

You could (or may be able to) use `float="outside"` to float your symbol to the outside of the page.  However, it's not clear to me from FOP's stated limitations on `fo:float` support (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#floats) whether `float="outside"` is supported or not (although it is supported by other XSL formatters, including AH Formatter).

Comment: I confirm that FOP 2.1 does **not** support `float="outside"` (or `"inside"`).